# How would I separate this text with a Substring?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a flatfile that contains data like this (Please note that EACH LINE = ONE ROW and is all in 1 Field and that's why I'm using a Substring to separate it out and make a new table with better formatted data):

```
011000015O0110000150122415000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK                1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E.              ATLANTA             GA303094470877372245711     
011000028O0110000151072811000000000STATE STREET BANK AND TRUST COMPANY JAB2NW                              N. QUINCY           MA021710000617664240011     
011000138O0110000151101310000000000BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.               8001 VILLA PARK DRIVE               HENRICO             VA232280000800446013511
```

I'm trying to separate it out; however, I don't know how to find the first non int number in a SUBSTRING function. I'm profiling this data. So far, I have separated the first 2 parts of this number sequence that I need; however, I'm having trouble finding out a good way to separate the beginning of the Name of the Bank (FEDERAL RESEVE BANK). It seems to be 35 integers before the name Starts, however, how do I find the length of the name?

I really only need help up until the bank name, i.e. "FEDERAL RESERVE BANK". After that I can hopefully figure the rest out.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1, 0,10) ROUTING_NUMBER,
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1,11,9) FEDRESERVE_NUM,
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1,
FROM srcFlatFile.dbo.fedachdir2018
```

This is what I need (the "O" doesn't need it's own column and the '000000000' and '122203950' are not needed right now):

```
011000015 O 011000015 0122415 000000000 FEDERAL RESERVE BANK                1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E.              ATLANTA             GA 30309-4470 8773722457 11     
011000028 O 011000015 1072811 000000000 STATE STREET BANK AND TRUST COMPANY JAB2NW                              N. QUINCY           MA 02171-0000 6176642400 11     
011000138 O 011000015 1101310 000000000 BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.               8001 VILLA PARK DRIVE               HENRICO             VA 23228-0000 8004460135 11
```

Comment: is this an issue?

Comment: It would greatly help my code by allowing me to not depend on fixed field lengths but on just the length of what the name is. So, yes, this is an issue and I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a Fixed Width file export. Whoever provided the file to you should have given you an import specification, but it sounds like perhaps they didn't do that for you. It's not "all one field", though. It's just that the fields are set lengths, and the spec, if you had it, would tell you where to break it up.

Far and away the easiest thing to do is to use SSIS, or, if this is a one-off import, the Import Data wizard (which, for the record, just writes you an SSIS package; and you should use the "Save package to file system" option, because I've never seen a "one off" import that only happened once). Then, once the data is in a table, do whatever else you need to do with it.

Hopefully you know what the first five columns are, but the rest of the spec is pretty self-explanatory:

```
+-------------------+--------+
|       Name        |  Width |
+-------------------+--------+
| Column1           |      9 |
| Column2           |      1 |
| Column3           |      9 |
| Column4           |      7 |
| Column5           |      9 |
| BankName          |     36 |
| BankAddy          |     36 |
| BankCity          |     20 |
| BankStateCd       |      2 |
| BankZip           |      9 |
| BankAreaCode      |      3 |
| BankPhone         |     10 |
| BankCountryPrefix |      2 |
+-------------------+--------+
```

The address might really be two 18 character columns, but from the sample data it looks like just one bigger column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Substring method, (length is hardcoded)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Sampletable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE Sampletable 
GO

CREATE TABLE Sampletable 
(
Samples VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Sampletable VALUES 
('011000015O0110000150122415000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK'),
('011000028O0110000151072811000000000STATE STREET BANK AND TRUST COMPANY'),
('011000138O0110000151101310000000000BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.')

SELECT SUBSTRING (Samples,1,9) AS [1],SUBSTRING (Samples,10,1) AS [2],
SUBSTRING (Samples,11,9) AS [3],SUBSTRING (Samples,20,7) AS [4],
SUBSTRING (Samples,27,9) AS [5],REPLACE(Samples,SUBSTRING(Samples,1,35),'') AS [6]
FROM Sampletable
```